.desktop files on Red Hat desktop launches gedit ONLY from desktop shortcut
I have .desktop files (shortcuts) on a RHEL 8.8 machine that are set up correctly and work on other RHEL systems, but for some reason, whenever trying to launch (double click) on these desktop files FROM the GUI it opens them in gedit.
There used to be an option when right clicking on these files to "Allow Launching" which was part of our installation instructions for customers but that doesn't exist in the RMC menu anymore for any of the .desktop files.
They are all set to executable. I installed the GNOME Tweaks and other add-on extensions and it's all set to use shortcuts. My software's shortcut is proprietary so I'm sharing one for Perforce.
Getting a crash course in MIME types and GNOME desktop, but nothing is helping. I am comparing the /usr/share/application and /usr/share/packages locations and so far everything matches the systems where this functionality WORKS.
Here's an example of one of the .desktop files:
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
MimeType=application/x-desktop
Name=P4V
Icon=/home/tcgllc/Perforce/p4v-2023.4.2558838/lib/P4VResources/icons/p4v.svg
Exec=/home/tcgllc/Perforce/p4v-2023.4.2558838/bin/p4v
Terminal=false
Path=/home/tcgllc/Perforce/p4v-2023.4.2558838/bin

One crazy aspect of this is that double clicking on them in the Files app (opened to ~/Desktop) works!  It's JUST the .desktop files, in ~/Desktop, via double clicking on the gui.
Tried all of the following:
Copied P4V.desktop to /usr/share/applications
gio set P4V.desktop metadata::trusted true
gio set P4V.desktop metadata::trusted yes
xdg-mime default P4V.desktop application/x-desktop
update-desktop-database /usr/share/applications
update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
xdg-desktop-menu install /usr/share/applications/P4V.desktop --novendor

when I run file --mime P4V.desktop the output is
/home/tcgllc/Desktop/P4V.desktop: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

I have the free RHEL Developer subscription but it's self supported, RHEL Knowledgebase has been searched. I've been pulling my hair out for 2 days. I've tried everything I could find on google and I'm screaming uncle.
If anyone can help me with this issue I would be immensely grateful!
TIA
KL
Editing to add what I've tried based on chubblywarner's comments (sorry new here, I just saw it said to edit original post!?)
YES you are correct in all of your initial points. I ended up re-creating the .desktop file and removing the copies of it I had placed all over the system to "start fresh".
$ nano P4V.desktop (made updates to .desktop file)
$ chmod +x ~/Desktop/P4V.desktop 
$ sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
$ sudo update-desktop-database
$ gio info P4V.desktop

standard::icon: application-x-desktop, text-x-generic
  standard::content-type: application/x-desktop
  standard::fast-content-type: application/x-desktop
  standard::symbolic-icon: application-x-desktop-symbolic, text-x-generic-symbolic, application-x-desktop, text-x-generic
  access::can-read: TRUE
  access::can-write: TRUE
  access::can-execute: TRUE
  access::can-delete: TRUE
  access::can-trash: TRUE
  access::can-rename: TRUE
  owner::user: tcgllc
  owner::user-real: tcgllc
  owner::group: tcgllc
  selinux::context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
  xattr-sys::security.selinux: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
  metadata::nautilus-icon-position: 0,283
$ xdg-mime default P4V.desktop application/x-desktop
$ gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences executable-text-activation
'launch'
$ grep -r "application/x-desktop" ~/.config /etc/xdg
/home/tcgllc/.config/mimeapps.list:application/x-desktop=org.gnome.gedit.desktop;
/home/tcgllc/.config/mimeapps.list:application/x-desktop=P4V.desktop
$ getenforce
Permissive

I'm not sure if anything below is useful, but it does look like there are warnings, permission issues?
$ journalctl -b | grep -i desktop

....
Aug 29 15:52:04 TEW-LINUX sudo[9531]:   tcgllc : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/tcgllc/Desktop ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/update-desktop-database
Aug 29 15:52:21 TEW-LINUX sudo[9556]:   tcgllc : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/tcgllc/Desktop ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/update-desktop-database
Aug 29 15:53:12 TEW-LINUX sudo[9602]:   tcgllc : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/tcgllc/Desktop ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/xdg-mime default P4V.desktop application/x-desktop
Aug 29 15:53:52 TEW-LINUX gnome-session[2863]: gnome-session-binary[2863]: WARNING: Unable to inhibit system: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Permission denied
Aug 29 15:53:52 TEW-LINUX gnome-session-binary[2863]: WARNING: Unable to inhibit system: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Permission denied
Aug 29 15:53:53 TEW-LINUX gnome-shell[3101]: desktop-icons: File System Manager.desktop is writable by others - will not allow launching
Aug 29 15:54:51 TEW-LINUX sudo[9689]:   tcgllc : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/tcgllc/Desktop ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/xdg-mime default P4V.desktop application/x-desktop
Aug 29 15:55:15 TEW-LINUX sudo[9722]:   tcgllc : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/usr/share/applications ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/rm P4V.desktop
Aug 29 16:23:31 TEW-LINUX gnome-session[2863]: gnome-session-binary[2863]: WARNING: Unable to inhibit system: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Permission denied
Aug 29 16:23:31 TEW-LINUX gnome-session-binary[2863]: WARNING: Unable to inhibit system: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Permission denied
Aug 29 16:26:53 TEW-LINUX org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3101]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2400101
Aug 29 16:29:05 TEW-LINUX sudo[11737]:   tcgllc : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/tcgllc/Desktop ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
Aug 29 16:29:16 TEW-LINUX sudo[11753]:   tcgllc : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/tcgllc/Desktop ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/update-desktop-database
Aug 29 16:31:35 TEW-LINUX org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3101]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2000007
                                                     _updateDesktopIfChanged@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/desktopManager.js:415:21
                                                     _monitorDesktopFolder/<@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/desktopManager.js:368:89
Aug 29 16:32:27 TEW-LINUX gnome-shell[3101]: desktop-icons: File System Manager.desktop is writable by others - will not allow launching
Aug 29 16:33:09 TEW-LINUX sudo[11889]:   tcgllc : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/tcgllc/Desktop ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
Aug 29 16:33:41 TEW-LINUX sudo[11899]:   tcgllc : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/tcgllc/Desktop ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/update-desktop-database
Aug 29 16:36:02 TEW-LINUX org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3101]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2400101

Then, the final few commands:
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.32.2
$ rpm -qa | grep gnome
gnome-desktop3-3.32.2-1.el8.x86_64
gnome-shell-3.32.2-50.el8.x86_64
gnome-shell-extension-common-3.32.1-39.el8_10.noarch
gnome-shell-extension-top-icons-3.32.1-39.el8_10.noarch
chrome-gnome-shell-10.1-7.el8.x86_64
gnome-online-accounts-3.28.2-4.el8.x86_64
gnome-system-monitor-3.28.2-1.el8.x86_64
gnome-control-center-filesystem-3.28.2-37.el8.noarch
gnome-terminal-3.28.3-3.el8.x86_64
gnome-shell-extension-places-menu-3.32.1-39.el8_10.noarch
gnome-screenshot-3.26.0-3.el8.x86_64
gnome-session-wayland-session-3.28.1-19.el8.x86_64
gnome-bluetooth-libs-3.34.3-1.el8.x86_64
gnome-session-xsession-3.28.1-19.el8.x86_64
gnome-keyring-pam-3.28.2-1.el8.x86_64
gnome-control-center-3.28.2-37.el8.x86_64
gnome-shell-extension-window-list-3.32.1-39.el8_10.noarch
gnome-font-viewer-3.28.0-1.el8.x86_64
gnome-user-docs-3.28.2-1.el8.noarch
gnome-menus-3.13.3-11.el8.x86_64
gnome-tweaks-3.28.1-7.el8.noarch
gnome-video-effects-0.4.3-3.el8.noarch
gnome-themes-standard-3.22.3-4.el8.x86_64
gnome-shell-extension-horizontal-workspaces-3.32.1-39.el8_10.noarch
gnome-classic-session-3.32.1-39.el8_10.noarch
gnome-initial-setup-3.28.0-11.el8.x86_64
gnome-color-manager-3.28.0-3.el8.x86_64
gnome-calculator-3.28.2-2.el8.x86_64
gnome-shell-extension-user-theme-3.32.1-39.el8_10.noarch
gnome-settings-daemon-3.32.0-19.el8.x86_64
libgnomekbd-3.26.0-4.el8.x86_64
gnome-shell-extension-launch-new-instance-3.32.1-39.el8_10.noarch
gnome-software-3.36.1-11.el8.x86_64
gnome-bluetooth-3.34.3-1.el8.x86_64
gnome-session-3.28.1-19.el8.x86_64
gnome-keyring-3.28.2-1.el8.x86_64
gnome-autoar-0.2.3-2.el8.x86_64
gnome-shell-extension-apps-menu-3.32.1-39.el8_10.noarch
gnome-boxes-3.36.5-8.el8.x86_64
gnome-terminal-nautilus-3.28.3-3.el8.x86_64
gnome-logs-3.28.5-3.el8.x86_64
gnome-getting-started-docs-3.28.2-1.el8.noarch
gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-3.32.1-39.el8_10.noarch
gnome-disk-utility-3.28.3-2.el8.x86_64
gnome-remote-desktop-0.1.8-3.el8.x86_64
gnome-characters-3.28.2-1.el8.x86_64
$ 
$ ls -l ~/Desktop/P4V.desktop
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 tcgllc tcgllc 298 Aug 29 16:32 /home/tcgllc/Desktop/P4V.desktop

I appreciate SO MUCH all of your help in diagnosing this weirdness. Unfortunately, I still only get gedit double clicking on the .desktop file ON the desktop. And still, when I double click on the .desktop files in the Files App, it will launch correctly. I'm going to include a visual of this. I do get the "Untrusted application launcher" pop up the first time running P4V.desktop in the Files App. Thereafter, the icon shows as expected.

Also, if I am responding to or communicating with you incorrectly, let me know what I should do if different. :)  TYSVM

The Problem
From what I understand:

Your .desktop files (shortcuts) work fine on other RHEL systems
Double-clicking them from the GUI opens them in gedit instead of launching the app
The "Allow Launching" option is missing from the right-click menu
Weirdly, double-clicking in the Files app (when opened to ~/Desktop) works fine
You've already tried a bunch of solutions (nice work on the troubleshooting!)

Initial Thoughts
The first thing that jumps out at me is the MIME type issue. When you ran file --mime P4V.desktop, it showed up as text/plain instead of application/x-desktop. That's probably why your system is defaulting to gedit.
The .desktop File
Let's start by tweaking your .desktop file a bit. Here's a modified version that might work better:
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
MimeType=application/x-desktop
Name=P4V
Icon=/home/tcgllc/Perforce/p4v-2023.4.2558838/lib/P4VResources/icons/p4v.svg
Exec="/home/tcgllc/Perforce/p4v-2023.4.2558838/bin/p4v" %f
Terminal=false
Path=/home/tcgllc/Perforce/p4v-2023.4.2558838/bin
Categories=Development;

The main changes here are:

Added quotes around the Exec command and included %f at the end
Added a Categories entry

Troubleshooting Steps
Alright, let's go through this step-by-step. Some of these you might have already tried, but it's worth giving them another shot:

File Permissions: Make sure the file is executable.
chmod +x ~/Desktop/P4V.desktop


Update MIME Database: This helps the system recognize file types correctly.
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime


Update Desktop Database: This refreshes the system's knowledge of .desktop files.
sudo update-desktop-database


Check File Recognition: Let's see if the system is seeing the file correctly.
gio info ~/Desktop/P4V.desktop

Look for "standard::content-type". It should say "application/x-desktop".

Set Default Application: Tell the system to use your .desktop file for .desktop files (I know, it sounds weird).
xdg-mime default P4V.desktop application/x-desktop


Check GNOME Settings: Make sure GNOME is set to launch executables.
gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences executable-text-activation

If it says 'display', change it to 'launch':
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences executable-text-activation 'launch'


Look for Conflicts: Check if something else is trying to handle .desktop files.
grep -r "application/x-desktop" ~/.config /etc/xdg


Check SELinux: Sometimes SELinux can interfere.
getenforce

If it says "Enforcing", try:
sudo setenforce 0

Test your .desktop file. If it works now, you'll need to create an SELinux policy (that's a whole other can of worms).

Check Logs: Look for any errors related to desktop files.
journalctl -b | grep -i desktop



If All Else Fails
If none of that works (fingers crossed it does!), we might need to dig deeper. Could you run these commands and share the output?
gnome-shell --version
rpm -qa | grep gnome
ls -l ~/Desktop/P4V.desktop

This will give us more info about your GNOME setup and the specific .desktop file.
Wrapping Up
I know this is a lot to try, but hopefully one of these steps will solve the issue. If not, don't worry! We'll figure it out. Let me know how it goes, and we can brainstorm more ideas if needed.
Good luck!

I CANNOT thank you ENOUGH for helping me with this!  No luck (I tried all the commands you gave me) except there may be some type of permissions WARNINGS in the journalctl.  (gonna try to attach a log file to this for you to see - if not I'll paste it in)

Hi again - I updated my original post (I didn't know if I should update yours?) with comments and output. SO much appreciation.
